# Bad Connection: Tableau could not connect to the data source. Error Code: A7AED4D2

Tags: ssms, tableau-api, ssas-tabular, polybase

I am getting this error when I try to drag one of the measure/dimension on to the visual pane. The tableau server is connected with the SSAS database. I have installed the latest ole db drivers for the server. But the Polybase seems not to start. TCP/IP is enabled still the Polybase is not starting and I understand that it's required for cross-platform data access, but not sure if it is the case being here.

> An error occurred while communicating with data source 'Model
> (TabularProject2)'
>
> Bad Connection: Tableau could not connect to the data source.
>
> Error Code: A7AED4D2
>
> Unknown error communicating with data source (COM:0xC1010000)
>
> SELECT
>
> {[Measures].DefaultMember} DIMENSION PROPERTIES
> [MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME],[MEMBER_CAPTION] ON COLUMNS,
>
> NON EMPTY ['Customer Details$'].[Customer Names].[Customer
> Names].AllMembers DIMENSION PROPERTIES
> [MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME],[MEMBER_CAPTION] ON ROWS
>
> FROM [Model]

What should I do now?

Comment: We've recently started seeing the same error codes but with a different process. I wonder if it's related to a recent SSAS patch.